# Solve for $z$ in $4z^2+8|z|^2-3=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$$4z^2+8|z|^2-3=0$$

I have to find $z$.

$|z|^2 = z\cdot \bar{z}$, but I don't know if this helps in this situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can prove first that $z^2$ is real, and then use the fact that $|z|^2=|z^2|$.

Can you find $z^2$ then?

Comment: How do I prove that $z^2$ is real?

Comment: can you see any reason why the second and third term would be real? (taking the conjugate also helps, but this is simpler)

Comment: So finally it will be $4z^2+8z^2-3=0$? Thank you!

Comment: Carefull, $z$ is complex, so $z^2$ can be also negative....

Comment: @nikita2 The last two are $\pm i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: Answers: $z = \pm\frac12, \pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ (after corrections)